# Parsing Data from local websever

Tags: esp8266, web-server, http

i´m trying to build a little monitor of an ESP8266 and an OLED display that displayes the Status of a Robotarm.

The robotarm is controled by a RAMPSboard that has a webserver, so i can check the status from a browser. 
For that i´m trying to use the BasicHttpClient Sketch from Arduino to read the status and progress.

The problem is i.... don´t know how?
I guess i know where the data is in my HTML document, but i dont know how to call it via GET request.

With the modified BasicHttpClient Sketch i can read the whole html site and print it out on serial, but after weeks of reading and watching tutorials i´m still stucked.

Long story short.

i want to read "just" the status and progress off of that webserver, with a GET request

this is the part of HTML code where my data is...i guess:
here are 3 different times of the informations i´d like to "extract" and displayed on my little ESP8266 monitor

```
<span id="stat" title="Not Available">Idle</span>
<span id="stat" title="Not Available">Working</span>
<span id="stat" title="Not Available">Done</span>

<div class="progress-bar active" id="pgs" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0% Complete</div>   //äusseresHTML
<div class="progress-bar active" id="pgs" role="progressbar" style="width: 1%;">1% Complete</div>
<div class="progress-bar active" id="pgs" role="progressbar" style="width: 22%;">22% Complete</div>
```

and i just need to change that part of the sketch as it now prints out everything of the page:

```
void loop() {...

     ... Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = http.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
----->          String payload = http.getString();   <---as i understand here i ask for everything
          Serial.println(payload);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }
```

Hopefully someone has the time to take a look at that and point me to String i need to call.

BTW, i think the main problem why i couldn´t find the answer myself is my english isnt that professional for that kind of stuff, so im doin hard to understand similar tutorials

Comment: how is the progress bar updated?  ... are you able to see the update if you use a web browser on a PC?

Comment: you cannot get just a part of a web page by using the GET call ... pethaps you could use an XMLHttpRequest ... google `http xhr` ... as it stands, your question is not really related to the arduino at all

Comment: Good morning(from Germany), thank you for your fast answer.   i looked for http xhr and edited my question, i think i clarified my question a little more.as far as i understand this http xhr is for a Server to send status to a client, am i right?

Comment: Check the documentation of the RAMPSboard server. There may be a JSON endpoint that provides the data you are looking for in a format more amenable to being consumed by  a program. Failing that, you may want to search for a regex library for your ESP: that is the Swiss knife for parsing text strings.

Comment: Thank you, ill have a look at that

Comment: open the web page with a web browser ... press F12 (should work for most browsers) .... examine the data that is being sent by the server .... it may already be using xhr ... if it is, then you will see the GET request URL

Comment: i would loop though line-by-line, and if i see a smoking gun, process the line further to parse out the values encoded in the html markup using string commands.